Can flood basalt eruptions start in historical timescales?
So I ended up reading about flood basalt eruptions, which apparently have a relatively rapid onset, geologically speaking. This reminded me of Brandon Sanderson's Mistborn trilogy's world. However, I didn't find info about how rapid the onset can be, just that the eruptions themselves last less than a million years.
Just wondering whether one could realistically start in a given setting's recorded history (i.e. onset takes at most centuries) rather than being a thing of distant geological history, making the denizens of the world mistakenly assume it having something to do with historical events? Also, it's fine if it messes up the world and alters the climate somewhat as long as it's not apocalyptic.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It's worth remembering that there's an entire galaxy of Stack Exchange websites. This question might have been better asked on [earthscience.se].

JBH isn't wrong, you'd have gotten the same information, from me at least, I'd suggest losing the fantasy novel reference if you choose to cross post it though. In future you're also well advised to give the community an absolute minimum of 24 hours to reply before you accept an answer, this gives all time zones a chance to respond.

The longest walk begins with one step. Any geological phenomenon begins at one instant in time.
The well-known Deccan Traps large igneous province was formed in a series of very large volcanic eruptions. The entire series extended over about 650,000 years, but it was a series not one overlong never-ending eruption. There were several distinct high-intensity eruptive pulses, each about 10,000 to 20,000 years long. It all culminated in a world-ending massive eruption, which produced 1,000 km (621 miles) lava flows, the longest lava flows ever found. And yes, in the end it was apocalyptic; just ask the non-avian dinosaurs.
There is a fine article online, "Mercury linked to Deccan Traps volcanism, climate change and the end-Cretaceous mass extinction" by Gerta Keller et al., in Global and Planetary Change  194 (2020) (link to full PDF on Professor Keller's site). One figure in special deserves attention, as it shows several indicators including climatological estimations on very fine time scale. (Useless DOI DOI:10.1016/j.gloplacha.2020.103312 goes to Elsevier who want money.) A short summary (with the relevant figure) is available at Princeton Geosciences.
So that yes, of course it is possible for a flood basalt eruption to begin at some point in human history. It is of course possible for one of the high-intensity peaks of such a phenomenon to begin or to end on historical timescales. It is the entirety of the phenomenon which is vastly longer than human civilization history.

Thanks for the answer. So I guess it would be plausible that onset of such an event would happen within a century. However, it looks like Deccan Traps are one of the largest igneous provinces. Could a somewhat smaller one be less apocalyptic, instead merely being a massive headache rather than being civilization-ending?
Also, I thought that the dinos were killed off by a giant meteor rather than volcanic activity...

@Maza2456: The Chicxulub asteroid and the Deccan Traps basalt flood are the two top suspects, and it may even be the case that only one of them without the other would not have been enough. I gave the example of the Deccan Traps because this particular basalt flood has been very thoroughly investigated. (The possible link with the dinos is an incentive.)

Maybe but given the current level of mantle depletion it is increasingly unlikely. As eruptive activity continues over geological time the elements in the mantle that are involved in the formation of the basic, mafic and ultramafic melts, in particular Magnesium, Potassium, Sodium, and Calcium, that are required for flood basalts to form grow scarcer. This means that the mantle becomes higher in silica and the magmas it produces sticker and less likely to flow far from the vents they are coming from. The trick with a flood basalt is that it needs to flow without building up around the vent and putting weight on the upwelling lava that halts it's continued rise. I have seen estimates that say there is no longer enough light metals to facilitate the low viscosities required and papers that argue for it being borderline, others argue that there are probably still large elemental reserves under older continental blocks.
It should be noted that a repeat of a Deccan Traps type of event is not only possible it's currently expected, just not any time soon. Deccan was caused by the Indian Craton passing over the Réunion hotspot mantle plume. This effectively held a blowtorch to some of the oldest continental rock on Earth melting out massive volumes of geochemically basic rock forming elements that had been tied up since the Cambrian making the production of enormous volumes of basalt possible. The next incident of this kind is expected to occur with the continued closure of the Pacific Ocean bringing the Hawaii plume under North America.

I'm not really concerned about whether it could happen currently on Earth, just that whether it would be plausible on a fictional world. So I guess that counts as a "yes" then?

@Maza2456 Yeah sorry about that, see my second answer about the rate at which volcanism can erupt onto the scene, no pun intended.

My existing answer is me reading this as a current IRL question about the next flood basalt rather than a hypothetical about rate of onset of such eruptions in general. One theory holds that flood basalts occur at the antipodal point of large Impact Events due to the impact shockwaves initiating mantle plume activity.
If this theory is true, (and the timing and placement of many large igneous provinces is highly suggestive), then the onset of a flood basalt may occur within living memory of such an impact. The shockwaves would, the theory states, initiate immediate melt sorting, the mantle equivalent of liquefaction, resulting in an almost instantaneous upward migration of mantle material, this material still needs time to move through the asthenosphere and overlying crust but that's probably a matter of months-to-years not centuries. This is especially true if you're dealing with long lived fantasy races like Elves.
The onset of any volcanism can be an almost overnight event; in 1943 there was a corn field in the Mexican state of Michoacán, by 1952 there was a mountain called Parícutin over 400m tall that had destroyed ~230km2 of surrounding farmland. If anything I would expect a flood basalt to be even faster to develop than a traditional volcanic cone.

There is nothing preventing it to happen or start during historic times, at any moment.
On a smaller scale we have examples of long lasting eruptions: Mount Etna in Italy has frequently had long lasting eruption. Citing from Wikipedia

Since 1750, seven of Etna's eruptions have had duration of more than 5 years, more than any other volcano except Vesuvius.

The associated emission of lava is also quite important, so there is nothing barring it from happening on a larger scale.
